# How does vector::clear invoke destructors without losing allocated memory

Tags: c++, vector

The point of `std::vector::clear` is that it cuts the size of the array to 0 while [leaving the capacity unchanged](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear).  The destructors of the objects contained in the vector are invoked at the point of the `.clear()`.

What I don't understand is how the destructors can be invoked without freeing the memory the objects reside in.  Is there a known method to accomplish this with conventional C++?  Is there some kind of much lower level dark magic accomplishing this?

Comment: Related: http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call the destructor of an `Object` of class `Class`

```
Object.~Class();
```

`std::vector` manually does this.

Note that after you manually call the destructor, the destructor will still be called again if `Object` has automatic storage duration or allocated through `new` and then `delete`d, possibly resulting in undefined behavior (like double delete). Explicitly calling destructor works here because by default, `std::vector` uses *placement new* to construct the object on allocated raw storage, not regular *new*.

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't understand is how the destructors can be invoked without freeing the memory the objects reside in. Is there a known method to accomplish this with conventional C++?

The destructor is invoked explicitly. The standard says (at § 23.2.1) that every type in the container is required to allow this expression to be well formed:

```
(&a)->~X()
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>` contains a `std::allocator<T>` which is capable of doing this. In particular, see `std::allocator::destroy(T* ptr)`.

Behind the scenes, `std::allocator<T>` will do (something very similar to) `ptr->~T()`.